# Select timeout with Python OpenCV Raspbian RPi4 with single USB Webcam

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, usb, webcam, raspberry-pi4

**First my opencv installation process:**

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/16/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-raspbian-buster/

```
sudo apt-get install -y vim bc

#gain more SDCARD space; remove unneed software
###############################################
sudo apt-get purge -y wolfram-engine;
sudo apt-get purge -y libreoffice*;
sudo apt-get clean;
sudo apt-get autoremove -y;


###############################################
# install dependencies
###############################################

sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake pkg-config;
echo;echo;echo;
sudo apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng-dev;
echo;echo;echo;

sudo apt-get install -y libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev;
echo;echo;echo;
sudo apt-get install -y libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev;
echo;echo;echo;

sudo apt-get install -y libfontconfig1-dev libcairo2-dev;
echo;echo;echo;
sudo apt-get install -y libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev;
echo;echo;echo;

sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev;
echo;echo;echo;

sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev gfortran
echo;echo;echo;

sudo apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-103
echo;echo;echo;

sudo apt-get install -y libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libqt4-test python3-pyqt5
echo;echo;echo;

sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev
echo;echo;echo;



###############################################
# create virtual python environment (need pip, virtualenv , virtualenvwrapper)
###############################################

wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/pip

sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper


#EDIT .bashrc, add to bottom:
###############################################
# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

#save, exit .bashrc, reload:
###############################################
source ~/.bashrc

# now create the virtual environment (we're calling it 'cv')
###############################################
mkvirtualenv cv -p python3



###############################################
#INSTall opencv4 into 'cv' virtual environment using 'pip'
###############################################
pip install opencv-contrib-python

pip3 install matplotlib

###############################################
# I make sure I'm in the virtual env
###############################################
workon cv


###############################################
# the 'LD_PRELOAD' takes care of a startup error
###############################################
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0    python3
```

**Next, here is my python script:**
(i've tried it with and without setting the width x height)

```
import cv2

device = 0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

# if capture failed to open, try again
if not cap.isOpened():
    cap.open(device)

# only attempt to read if it is opened
if cap.isOpened:
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        else:
            print("Error reading capture device")
            break

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print("Failed to open capture device")
```

**The error output:**

select timeout
VIDIOC_DQBUF: Resource temporarily unavailable
Error reading capture device

Camera works fine using mjpg-streamer

**UPDATE:**
I didn't find the root issue but do have a workaround that is good enough for me (at least for now).

1. Run mjpg-streamer.  In my case, webcam is streaming at
   http://localhost:8083/?action=stream
2. Capture video from URL instead of from USB device number.
3. Modify code to keep grabbing the image

```
import cv2

webcamConnected = False

url = "http:/localhost:8082/?action=stream"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

# only attempt to read if it is opened
if cap.isOpened:
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        else:
            print("Error reading capture device")
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print("Failed to open capture device")
```